# How to check if an element of a user specified list exists in another user defined list in drools

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I'm new to JBoss Drools and looking for some help please.

I'm looking to check that for each item in a list (contained within class X) whether there is a matching item in another list in class Y?

The lists will be filled with data from a database which is outwith my control, so I can't search for specific elements at all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking for - take your pick.

```
rule "check for each X.list in Y.list"
when
    X( $xl: list )
    $e: E() from $xl 
    Y( list contains $e )
then
    // Element $e from X.list also occurs in Y.list. 
end

rule "check for all X.list in Y.list at once"
when
    X( $xl: list )
    Y( list.containsAll( $xl ) )
then
    // all elements of X.list occurs in Y.list
end
```